# Unit Testing .NET Standard injection results in "wrong type"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, rhino-mocks, .net-standard

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 DLL, and a Unit Test Assembly (.NET 4.7.1 full framework).

In my Standard DLL, I have a constructor that allows my test to inject a fake `HttpClient`:

```
public Constructor(HttpClient fakeHttpClient) {...}
```

And in my Test, I have:

```
var fakeHttpClient = RhinoMocks.GenerateStub<HttpClient>();
```

(also tested using Moq):

```
var fakeHttpClient = new Mock<HttpClient>();
```

In my test I then have:

```
_ = new MyObject(fakeHttpClient);
```

(or with Moq)

```
_ = new MyObject(fakeHttpClient.Object);
```

It all compiles fine, and VS2017 allows me to F12 into the method.

However, at run-time, I get the message that it can't find the constructor and looking at the IL I see:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecial name
    instance void .ctor(class [**netstandard**]System.Net.Http.HttpClient fakeHttpClient) cil managed
```

So, my guess is that my stub is not seen as a .NET Standard object.

Any ideas how to solve this one?

**Edit** - in response to NightOwl888, the csproj for the test project is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="..\packages\NUnit.3.10.1\build\NUnit.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\NUnit.3.10.1\build\NUnit.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{7CD1BB70-97AC-4614-A4E3-C772BA0FAA4C}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>AssemblyUnderTest.Tests</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>AssemblyUnderTest.Tests</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">15.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <ReferencePath>$(ProgramFiles)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\$(VisualStudioVersion)\UITestExtensionPackages</ReferencePath>
    <IsCodedUITest>False</IsCodedUITest>
    <TestProjectType>UnitTest</TestProjectType>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="AssemblyA">
      <HintPath>..\..\AssemblyA\AssemblyA\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\AssemblyA.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AssemblyB, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\AssemblyB.1.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\AssemblyB.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.2.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.2.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.2.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.2.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.2.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="nunit.framework, Version=3.10.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NUnit.3.10.1\lib\net45\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Rhino.Mocks, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0b3305902db7183f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\RhinoMocks.3.6.1\lib\net\Rhino.Mocks.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.2.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Data.SqlClient.4.4.3\lib\net461\System.Data.SqlClient.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="TracerConstructionTests.cs" />
    <Compile Include="TracingTests.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\AssemblyUnderTest\AssemblyUnderTest.csproj">
      <Project>{b144431c-fa95-48a1-8d80-a7b9c652aec2}</Project>
      <Name>AssemblyUnderTest</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets" Condition="Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.5.0.0\build\StyleCop.MSBuild.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.5.0.0\build\StyleCop.MSBuild.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\NUnit.3.10.1\build\NUnit.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\NUnit.3.10.1\build\NUnit.props'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.2.0\build\net45\MSTest.TestAdapter.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.5.0.0\build\StyleCop.MSBuild.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\StyleCop.MSBuild.5.0.0\build\StyleCop.MSBuild.targets')" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of the `.csproj` file of the unit test project?

Comment: Does Rhino support .net standard?

Comment: @PmanAce: Not sure that RhinoMock does support .NET Standard 2.0.  It doesn't seem to be supported anymore from what I can tell, so re-wrote it using MOQ.  However, when I try passing my 'fakeHttpClient.Object' I get the same issue.

Comment: Going with Moq, I created an interface (IHttpClient) that has the GetAsync(...) method on it, but even that loosely coupled approach failed.